# Create loop to redefine label 10 times, with 0.1s time delay

Tags: c#, loops, timedelay

I am experienced in python programming but new to C# so I am including code in python which achieves what I want to do in C#. Essentially, I want to run a loop 10 times which, every 0.1 seconds, changes the value of a label with name "label12" to a random integer between 0 and 255. Here is how it may be achieved in python (using print instead of label):

```
import random
import time
for i in range(0,10):
   x = random.randint(0,255)
   print(x)
   time.sleep(0.1)
```

Thank you

Comment: I suggest you look up the following terms: "for loops", "delay or sleep", "label" with "C#" and you'll find what you're looking for. As an experienced programmer you should make sense out of them quite easily. Also, you'll need to know what the basics of a C# program are such as the Main method.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned a possible UI component, a *for loop* by itself will be of little benefit (as you will be holding up the message pump). It's possibly a *use-case* for the *async and await* pattern

```
private Random random = new Random();

public async Task DoStuff()
{
    int min = 0;
    int max = 255;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
       label12.Text = random.Next(min, max + 1);
       await Task.Delay(100); 
    }
}
```

<sub>***Note*** : If this is an event it's ok to use `async void`</sub>

```
public async void MyClickEvent(....)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

var random = new Random();
foreach ( var index in Enumerable.Range(0, 10) )
{
  label12.Text = random.Next(0, 256).ToString();
  Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

The upper bound is not included when generating the next random number.

The `Sleep` method takes milliseconds.

You can also use a `for` instead of a `foreach` and calling `Range`, that is faster:

```
for ( int index = 0; index < 10; index++ )
```